# SQL Date Filter on Two Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a table that has a date field (in `YYYYMM`) and two sales forecasts fields, but I want to query it in a way where I can query two different date ranges on separate columns but include them in the same output

The table is called SalesTable

Column Names are `CCYYMM` (date field), `FORECAST 1` (numbers), `FORECAST 2` (numbers)

Date Field Ranges from `201801` to `202412`

I want to create a query to get all sales values from `FORECAST 1` from `201801` to `202006` and all sales values for `FORECAST 2` from `202008` to `202112`, is this possible to do in a single query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Does the CCYYMM column contain unique values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a CASE to separate your totals by CCYYMM

```
select  sum(case when ccyymm between 201801 and 202006 then FORECAST1 end)   as FORCAST1
        , sum(case when ccyymm between 202008 and 202112 then FORECAST2 end) as FORCAST2
from    SalesTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to combine:

```
SELECT CCYYMM , FORECAST1
FROM SalesTable
WHERE CCYYMM BETWEEN x AND y
UNION ALL
SELECT CCYYMM , FORECAST2
FROM SalesTable
WHERE CCYYMM BETWEEN a AND b
```

Comment: This only brings back FORECAST1 column, FORECAST2 is missing

Comment: No it does not... look at line 5